# constructor template call 'no matching function to call'

Tags: c++, templates

I am currently writing a tree data structure for a project looking like this:

```
template<typename T>
  class tree
  {
    public:
      tree(T const&);
      // ...
    private:
      // ...
      std::auto_ptr<node<T>> mRoot;
  };


template<typename T>
tree<T>::tree(T const& data):
  mDepth(0),
  mRoot(nullptr)
{
  mRoot = new node<T>(data, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
}
```

where the constructor should initialize a tree with data as input in order to create the root node.

The node constructor looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct node
{
    // constructor & destructor
    node(T const&, 
         std::auto_ptr<node<T>>,
         std::auto_ptr<node<T>>,
         std::auto_ptr<node<T>>,
         std::auto_ptr<node<T>>,
         std::auto_ptr<node<T>>);

    // member
    T data;
    std::auto_ptr<node<T>> parent;
    std::auto_ptr<node<T>> firstChild, lastChild;
    std::auto_ptr<node<T>> nextSibling, prevSibling;
    int numChildren;
};

template<typename T>
node<T>::node(T const& data, 
              std::auto_ptr<node<T>> parent,
              std::auto_ptr<node<T>> firstChild,
              std::auto_ptr<node<T>> lastChild,
              std::auto_ptr<node<T>> nextSibling,
              std::auto_ptr<node<T>> prevSibling):
  data(data),
  parent(nullptr),
  firstChild(nullptr),
  lastChild(nullptr),
  nextSibling(nullptr),
  prevSibling(nullptr),
  numChildren(nullptr)
  {}
```

But if I try to call it within my main function like this

```
int foo = 1;
tree<int> mytree = tree<int>(foo);
```

It fails with the following error:

```
tree.h: In instantiation of 'tree<T>::tree(const T&) [with T = int]':
main.cpp:9:35:   required from here
tree.h:39:9: error: no matching function for call to 'node<int>::node(const int&, std::nullptr_t, std::nullptr_t, std::nullptr_t, std::nullptr_t, std::nullptr_t)'
   mRoot = new node<T>(data, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
```

The main problem is that I kind of reused the structure from an old self-implemented linked list where everything is working properly.

Maybe I am just to blind to find the main mistake but it would be nice if one of you would have an idea for that.

Answer (score 1):

`std::auto_ptr` does not have an implicit conversion fro pointer type, which means this kind of initialization is not allowed:

```
std::auto_ptr<node<T>> n = nullptr;
```

You can fix the immediate problem by changing the relevant constructor signature to

```
node(T const&, node*, node*, node*, node*, node*);
```

Note that your constructor implementation is not even attempting to use the `auto_ptr` parameters. Your compiler should give you warnings about that if suitable configured. Presumably you want to do something like this:

```
template<typename T>
node<T>::node(T const& data, 
              node<T>* parent,
              node<T>* firstChild,
              node<T>* lastChild,
              node<T>* nextSibling,
              node<T>* prevSibling):
  data(data),
  parent(parent),
  firstChild(firstChild),
  lastChild(lastChild),
  nextSibling(nextSibling),
  prevSibling(prevSibling),
  numChildren(numChildren)
{}
```

Finally, note that `std::auto_ptr` is deprecated in C++11. If you can use dialects newer than C++03, consider `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: well actually that fixed the problem for the moment, but I want `parent, firstChild ...` to be a node, so I guess you meant `node<T>` when you were typing T in the last 5 parameters of the constructor.